# How to run go command using only vendor dependencies?

Tags: go, vendor

I keep running into the issue where I install dependencies locally, it works fine, I push to continuous integration server, and then it breaks because I forgot to `godep save ./...` the dependency.

How can I run the `go` command but require `vendor` imports?

**Edit:**

I'm using `go1.6`. I want the command to fail if a 3rd-party dependency *does **not** resolve* to vendor. In other words, is there a way to stop resolving dependencies in `$GOPATH` during tests?

I can't change the environment variable because then none of my project modules can be resolved. How can I force vendor dependencies?

Comment: This is a vague question to me. What go version are you using? Have you considered trying the `vendor` directory that go supports in 1.5 and above?

Comment: @squiguy edited. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: This is something which would need to be done by the tools you use to vendor. I don't know if godep can list missing packages, but I know others like `govendor` and `glide` can be used to do that. If you want something checked on commit, push, etc, that's what git hooks are for.

Comment: I know it's not an answer to suggest other tools, but this is the reason I use [gb](https://getgb.io).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent builder to scan `$GOPATH` for packages. It seems, that you use not really good flow for manage dependencies. I recommend you to use `glide` for a vendoring.

Most recommended workflow:

1. Keep actual list of dependencies in `glide.yaml`.
2. Run `glide up` after any changes in `glide.yaml`. It will install all dependencies to `vendor` directory and generate `glide.lock` with fixed package versions. Commit `glide.lock` to VCS. **Do not** change manually `glide.lock`.
3. **Do not** commit `vendor` directory to VCS.
4. Run `glide install` on your CI or build server to install dependencies by `glide.lock` to `vendor`.
5. Build.

A migration from `godep` to `glide` may be done easily, because `glide` has a command to migrate `Godeps.json` to `glide.yaml`.